# Do I need to redefine the member selector operator in a User-Defined Type?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, operator-overloading

I'm likely doing something boneheaded here, and I'd like a pointer (pardon the pun).

I've defined the following class:

```
ref class CoordinatePair {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    CoordinatePair();
    CoordinatePair(int xInput, int yInput);
    CoordinatePair(CoordinatePair ^Other);
    //CoordinatePair& operator->();
};
```

Fairly simple. I find that I can select members using the `->` operator within the class's namespace with no ill effects. For example, the following compiles:

```
CoordinatePair::CoordinatePair(CoordinatePair ^Other) {
    x = Other->x;
    y = Other->y;
}
```

Groovy. Yet, when I try to compile this, I get problems.

```
CoordinatePair^ Coordinates::TranslateCoords(CoordinatePair^ WorldCoords) {
    CoordinatePair^ newCoords = gcnew CoordinatePair();
    float coordsRatio = 0.0;
    //Translate X
    coordsRatio = (float) WorldCoords->x / WorldBounds->x;
    newCoords->x = (int) (coordsRatio * PixelBounds->x);
    //Translate Y
    coordsRatio = 0.0;
    coordsRatio = (float) WorldCoords->y / WorldBounds->y;
    newCoords->y = (int) (coordsRatio * PixelBounds->y);
    return newCoords;
}
```

(Note, in the above code, `WorldBounds` is a member of the `Coordinates` class. It itself is a `CoordinatePair` that defines the plane for my project.)

Specifically I get this error:

```
.\Coordinates.cpp(95) : error C2819: type 'CoordinatePair' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
```

Huh. Well, okay. My attempt to research this problem drove me to try overloading the operator. So, I added the following in the class declaration:

```
CoordinatePair^ operator->();
```

And I defined it like so:

```
CoordinatePair^ CoordinatePair::operator->() {
    return this;
}
```

That made the compiler **even angrier!** :-(

```
.\Coordinates.cpp(17) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(17) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(18) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(18) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(62) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(95) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(95) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(95) : error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
.\Coordinates.cpp(95) : warning C4280: 'operator ->' was self recursive through type 'CoordinatePair'
        y:\documents\wende-project\c3\wende_c3_executioncode\wende_c3_executioncode\c3_display\c3_app\Coordinates.h(7) : see declaration of 'CoordinatePair'
```

[Looking up the error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kty7akd3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) gave me the following definition:

> *application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'type'*
>
> A redefinition of the class member access operator contains a recursive return statement. To redefine the -> operator with recursion, you must move the recursive routine to a separate function called from the operator override function.

I clearly don't know what I'm doing here and need to be set in the right direction. Help?

Comment: This error is typically given when you have an instance or a reference to an instance (instead of a pointer).  So you should write instance.x instead of instance->x.  What's the definition of WorldsBounds in your code?

Comment: The compiler will error on that, too. It complains that the type is `CoordinatePair ^` and asks if I meant to use `->`. I updated my question with context on what `WorldBounds` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick said in the comments, you've got `WorldBounds` as type `CoordinatePair` when it should be `CoordinatePair^`. As you mentioned, that fix causes other compiler errors, you'll need to go through all the places you currently do `WorldBounds.x` and replace it with `WorldBounds->x`.

For a `ref class`, you'll almost always want to use the `^`. There are situations where you'll want to leave it off, but they're rare.

Comment: That was dense of me. >.< I'll try this out when I get home.

Comment: Turns out I really was that dumb. It makes total sense now that I think of it, the `->` won't do member selection when I'm not dealing with a reference. Thanks.